# Add a "not voted on" tab to the synonyms page

Tags: feature-request, voting, tag-synonyms, tabs

When i'm looking at the tag synonyms page, in order to see whether i've voted on a synonym yet I have to go to the voting page. It would be easier to vote if there was a tab for unvoted pending synonyms on the overview page.

Comment: We've been asking for this kind of thing in the 10k tools for ages so we can see which questions we've voted to close and delete... maybe Waffles can work on that instead.